# Change sheet Name with PHP Google Spreadsheet api

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to change the Sheet Range name from one of my spreadsheets with php, but it is not working:

```
$requests = [
    new \Google_Service_Sheets_Request([
        'updateSheetProperties' => [
            'properties' => [
                'namedRangeId'=>$sheetID,
                'namedRange' => 'newRangeSheetNAME'
            ],
            'fields' => 'UpdateNamedRangeRequest'
        ],
    ])
];


$batchUpdateRequest = new \Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest(['requests' => $requests]);
$service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($this->newFileID, $batchUpdateRequest);
```

Why this is not working?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `updateNamedRange` request directly instead of updating the sheet properties. `updateSheetProperties` is a separate request altogether.

**JSON representation:**

```
{
  "namedRange": {
    object (NamedRange)
  },
  "fields": string
}
```

**Sample Request:**

```
$requests = [
    new \Google_Service_Sheets_Request([
        'updateNamedRange' => [
            'namedRange' => [
                'namedRangeId' => $sheetID,
                'name' => 'newRangeSheetNAME'
            ],
            'fields' => 'name'
        ],
    ])
];
```

For more information and how to use this in PHP you can refer to the documentation:

[updateNamedRange request](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#UpdateNamedRangeRequest)

[PHP reference](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Sheets_UpdateNamedRangeRequest.html)

Comment: could you correct my code? Because I am new to php and do not really know how to use that information in the documentation.

Comment: I added a sample request template for ````updateNamedRange````. I would not be able to test it, but it works as a starting point.